# Maintain an ArrayList of unique arrays in java

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I maintain an `ArrayList` of unique arrays?

For instance, if I have the following arrays:

```
int [] a = {1,2,3};
int [] b = {2,1,3};
int [] c = {2,1,3};
```

According to my logic I am considering unique combinations. So in the case above `a = b = c` because they all contain `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`.

Ideally I am wondering if there is a data structure in Java that recognizes this.

I tried the following:

```
Set<int []> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
int [] x = {1,2,3};
int [] z = {2,1,3};
int [] m = {2,1,3};

result.add(x);
result.add(z);
result.add(m);

for(int [] arr: result){
    printArray(arr);
}
```

My output was:

```
1 2 3
2 1 3
2 1 3
```

Ideally I would want my output to only print one of the combinations above.

Comment: If element order is insignificant and duplicates are not allowed, then using a `Set<Integer>` instead of an `int[]` will provide for the equality relation you want.

Comment: Is your array size fixed at 3? If yes, you could implement a class that computes a hashcode for the 3 elements.

Comment: @SomeDude, not only for fixed size, but he can writes a custom hash function for equality check.

Comment: @MaskedMan Yes, but writing a hashcode for 3 elements is easier than for 50 elements I presume.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - but Set<Integer> would mean i would add integers individually right? How do i maintain my combo of 3 numbers?

Comment: @Dinero, `Set<Integer>` *in place of `int[]`*.  So your `result` would be a `Set<Set<Integer>>`, with each element being a Set holding however many integers you wish.

Comment: A `Set` of a `Set` likely won't work, since it's likely to just compare the address of the object, rather than the contents of the object, just like every other complex object comparison, so it'll see them as different every time. This sounds like it needs a home-grown class to manage this, IMO.

Comment: @computercarguy : you're completely wrong. The main set will use the hashcode implementation of its set elements. For most well-implemented collections, hashcode() are called recursively on its elements. It's just for arrays and for default (non-overriden) hashcode implementation that it uses the address.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think hashCode for elements inside a `Set<Integer>` is just an addition of individual codes as I can see from implementation in `AbstractSet` class : `public int hashCode() {
        int h = 0;
        Iterator<E> i = iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            E obj = i.next();
            if (obj != null)
                h += obj.hashCode();
        }
        return h;
    }` In that case `Set<Set<Integer>>` won't work. It would consider `{0,1,2}` and `{1,1,1}` equal.

Comment: @SomeDude, a `Set` that implemented `equals()` that way would not correctly implement the `Set` contract.  Note well that it is indeed `equals()` that matters here, and although objects that equal each other should have the same hash code, objects that have the same hash code are not always equal to each other.

Comment: @computercarguy, a correct `java.util.Set` implementation relies on elements' `equals()` methods to determine whether they are equal.  And a correct `java.util.Set` implementation provides an `equals()` method for itself that implements the conventional sense of set equality: two `Set`s are equal if and only if they have the same elements (where "same" is again defined in terms of `equals()`).

Comment: @Dinero : could your arrays have several times the same elements? Like `[1, 1, 2]` ? If yes, then the `Set<Set>` approach would be wrong as `[1, 2, 1]` and `[2, 1]` would be considered the same.

Comment: @JohnBollinger even the `equals` doesn't serve the purpose. What `AbstractSet` in Java does is `return containsAll(c);` what if you compare `{1,1,1}` and `{1,1,1,0}` ?

Comment: @SomeDude, my recommendation to use a `Set` is explicitly predicated on the provision that it is not required to support duplicate elements.  With that said, you've missed something in your consideration of the `AbstractSet` source: it uses `containsAll()` only if the two sets' sizes are the same.  Honestly, though, you really ought to be looking at [the API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), not the implementation.  In any case, the Set `{1}` is unequal to the Set `{1,0}` (and *vice versa*). Try it out if you don't believe me.

Comment: The title of the question explicitly mentions `ArrayList`, although the question is rather about a `Set`. Are there any objections to changing the title to something like *"Maintain a Set..."* or *"Maintain a collection..."*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a method to add if not equals like so :

```
public static Set<int[]> addIfNotExist(Set<int[]> result, int[] array) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
    boolean check = result.stream()
            .anyMatch(a -> {
                Arrays.sort(a);
                return Arrays.equals(a, array);
            });
    if (check) {
        return result;
    } else {
        result.add(array);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can call your method like so :

```
result = addIfNotExist(result, x);
result = addIfNotExist(result, z);
result = addIfNotExist(result, m);
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

Or if you use a static `Set`, you can just use :

```
static Set<int[]> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] x = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] z = {2, 1, 3};
    int[] m = {2, 1, 3};

    addIfNotExist(result, x);
    addIfNotExist(result, z);
    addIfNotExist(result, m);

    for (int[] arr : result) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}

public static void addIfNotExist(Set<int[]> result, int[] array) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
    boolean check = result.stream()
            .anyMatch(a -> {
                Arrays.sort(a);
                return Arrays.equals(a, array);
            });
    if (!check) {
        result.add(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a java question that you may be able to help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792705/java-cannot-find-symbol-symbol-class-item

Comment: @Dinero sorry your question is deleted can you undelete it please then you will get answer ;)

Comment: @YCF_L Isn't invoking `Arrays.sort` every time for every array to costly? From what I understand this method works in-place, so by invoking `addIfNotExist`, we're practically saving a sorted array, so we don't have to sort all stored arrays again on another invocation. Correct me if I'm wrong;>

Comment: Thank you @Andronicus you are totally correct, I will edit it :-)

Comment: @YCF_L, no! Thank YOU for all the great answers you're posting on SO!

Comment: You are welcome @Andronicus, thank you too, you also provide many good answers too 

Answer (score 5):

It definitely feels hacky and wrong, but you could use a `TreeSet` with a custom `Comparator`. Depending on your needs this might actually work, but at least note that this is breaking the general contract of the `Set` interface.

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Set<int[]> result = new TreeSet<>(new Hack());
        int[] x = {1,2,3};
        int[] z = {2,1,3};
        int[] m = {2,1,3};

        result.add(x);
        result.add(z);
        result.add(m);

        for (int[] arr : result) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }
}

class Hack implements Comparator<int[]> {

    @Override
    public int compare(int[] e1, int[] e2) {
        int[] copy1 = Arrays.copyOf(e1, e1.length);
        int[] copy2 = Arrays.copyOf(e2, e2.length);
        Arrays.sort(copy1);
        Arrays.sort(copy2);
        return Arrays.compare(copy1, copy2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

If you are still on Java 8 use this `Hack` implementation:

```
class Hack implements Comparator<int[]> {

    @Override
    public int compare(int[] e1, int[] e2) {
        int[] copy1 = Arrays.copyOf(e1, e1.length);
        int[] copy2 = Arrays.copyOf(e2, e2.length);
        Arrays.sort(copy1);
        Arrays.sort(copy2);
        int cmp = Integer.compare(copy1.length, copy2.length);
        if (cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < copy1.length; i++) {
            cmp = Integer.compare(copy1[i], copy2[i]);
            if (cmp != 0) {
                return cmp;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like it would be slow due to tree degeneracy at best and wrong at worst--if `compare` does not present a symmetric relation then the tree will either turn into a degenerate tree, or will simply malfunction.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov : a TreeSet in java is a Red-Black tree so it will not turn into a degenerate tree.

Comment: @Ricola OK, I take back my remark about the tree becoming degenerate (I do see that the javadoc guarantees log-time ops with some sort of balanced tree). However, this simply malfunctions with an example: https://gist.github.com/hexafraction/607329bdc33c27a9f3b6044beec48137 (note first and last lines of the final output). This definitely needs to have a real, symmetric comparison/

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov: The `compare` implementation was a bit too sloppy. Thanks for the gist!

Comment: Why is it hacky actually ?

Comment: With Java 9+, you can simply use [Arrays.compare()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#compare-int:A-int:A-)

Comment: @Ricola: Good point! Will change it, Java 9+ should be standard nowadays.

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk: I consider it hacky because the ordering as implemented is not consistent with equals (i.e. `{1, 2, 3}.compareTo({1, 3, 2}) == 0` but `{1, 2, 3}.equals({1, 3, 2}) == false`) and thus breaking the contract of `Set`. This may lead to nasty surprises.

Comment: I would have left both ways. Java 8 is still pretty standard and supported until december 2020.

Answer (score 2):

**If we assume that your arrays cannot contain several time the same integer** (like `[1, 1, 2]`) then your definition of uniqueness (having the same elements regardless of the order) for your array is the one of a Set, so you could use a Set of Set.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Set<Set<Integer>> result = new HashSet<>();
    int [] x = {1,2,3};
    int [] z = {2,1,3};
    int [] m = {2,1,3};

    result.add(arrayToSet(x));
    result.add(arrayToSet(z));
    result.add(arrayToSet(m));

    System.out.println(result);

}

private static Set<Integer> arrayToSet(int [] arr){
    return Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

If you want to keep your arrays then which one should be kept when two arrays have the same elements? If it's the first one that has been added, you could use a `Map<Set<Integer>, int[]>` and then the values of your map contains the arrays.

---

If you need to consider that **it can contain several time the same integer**, then those are [Multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). You can implement a Multiset by a `Map<Integer, Integer>` which counts how many time each element is present. Then you can use the same implementation but with a `Set<Map<Integer, Integer>>` instead of a `Set<Integer>` :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Set<Map<Integer,Long>> result = new HashSet<>();
    int [] x = {1,2,3};
    int [] z = {1,2,2,3};
    int [] m = {1,2,3,2};

    result.add(arrayToMultiSet(x));
    result.add(arrayToMultiSet(z));
    result.add(arrayToMultiSet(m));

    System.out.println(result);

}

private static Map<Integer,Long> arrayToMultiSet(int [] arr){
    return Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Note : I used `Map<Integer,Long>` because `Collectors.counting()` returns a collector of `Long`.

Answer (score 2):

There already have been some answers, but some of them make certain assumptions that can not be derived from the question, others suggest certain changes that may be considered as workarounds, and others have certain drawbacks that should not be ignored.

Addressing some of them here:

- Changing the elements to a `Set<Integer>` makes the assumption that each element may only appear *once*. Additionally, if the existing code already *creates* the `int[]` arrays, and the downstream code *needs* the `int[]` arrays, then *using* the resulting data structure would be clumsy:

  ```
  int array[] = somewhere.getArray();
  Set<Integer> set = convert(array); // Convert array to set
  data.add(set);
  ...
  set = data.iterator().next();
  array = convert(set);              // Convert set to array
  somewhere.setArray(array);
  ```

  Depending on the size of the arrays, this may have an impact on performance and generate some memory overhad.
- Using a `TreeSet<int[]>` looks like a simple and reasonable solution. The nicest thing is that it can *directly* store the `int[]` arrays. But it has some drawbacks:

  1. It implies an ordering. It is no longer possible to use another `Set` implementation (like a `LinkedHashSet`) that retains the insertion order
  2. It may be a bit tricky to implement the comparison in a way that is [consistent with `equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and failing to do so will cause the set to no longer obey the general contract of the `Set` interface
  3. A simple but correct implementation of the comparison will *likely* involve *sorting* the arrays. This means that the arrays might either have to be modified by their insertion into the set, which is certainly not acceptable, or one would have to create defensive copies of the arrays. Here, one has to keep in mind that the copy and the sorting will have to be done *each and every time* when a new array is added, and it will have to be done **multiple** times while going down the tree. Although the number of comparisons will only be O(log(n)) for a set with `n` elements, sorting will take O(m log(m)) *each* time for arrays of length `m`, which may be prohibitively expensive.
- Similar arguments may be applied for the approaches that check whether an "equivalent" array already exists *before* inserting a new one. Additionally, these approaches are not based on a data structure, but have to be part of the code that *uses* the data structure.

---

For these reasons, I'd go for an approach that is basically the same as the one that [Mykhailo Moskura mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57484695/3182664) : It is based on a class that simply *wraps* the given `int[]` arrays, and implements `equals` and `hashCode` accordingly.

(Note that you *could* also let this class implement `Comparable`, adding some flexibility about whether it can be put into a `TreeSet`, if you are aware of the possible difficulties and drawbacks mentioned above...)

In the example below, this class is called `UnorderedIntArray`. *Conceptually*, it would be preferable to have a `Set<int[]>`, and the solution below has to use a `Set<UnorderedIntArray>`. But since this class only *wraps* an existing array, the performance- and memory overhead are practically *zero*, and I therefore still consider it as advantageous compared to converting between the `int[]` and some other data type. Also note that the `equals` method in the example below is not very efficient, but it is a simple way to ensure that the contracts of `equals` are obeyed.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class UniqueArraysTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<UnorderedIntArray> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        int[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] y = { 2, 1, 3 };
        int[] z = { 2, 1, 3 };

        int[] u = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] w = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 };

        result.add(new UnorderedIntArray(x));
        result.add(new UnorderedIntArray(y));
        result.add(new UnorderedIntArray(z));
        result.add(new UnorderedIntArray(u));
        result.add(new UnorderedIntArray(v));
        result.add(new UnorderedIntArray(w));

        for (UnorderedIntArray a : result) {
            int[] array = a.getArray();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }

    }

    static class UnorderedIntArray {
        private final int array[];

        UnorderedIntArray(int array[]) {
            this.array = array;
        }

        int[] getArray() {
            return array;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return IntStream.of(array).sum();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object object) {
            if (object == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (object == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!(object instanceof UnorderedIntArray)) {
                return false;
            }
            UnorderedIntArray that = (UnorderedIntArray)object;
            if (this.array.length != that.array.length) {
                return false;
            }
            // This is very simple, but not very efficient. More efficient
            // solutions could be implemented, but they are not trivial...
            Map<Integer, Long> thisFrequencies = computeFrequencies(this.array);
            Map<Integer, Long> thatFrequencies = computeFrequencies(that.array);
            return thisFrequencies.equals(thatFrequencies);
        }

        private Map<Integer, Long> computeFrequencies(int array[]) {
            return Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Arrays.toString(array);
        }

    }
}
```

For the input of

```
int[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] y = { 2, 1, 3 };
int[] z = { 2, 1, 3 };
int[] u = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
int[] v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
int[] w = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 };
```

the output is the expected

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper class which will contain an immutable instance variable of integer array and override hashcode :

```
public class ArrayWrapper {
   private final int[] a;

@Override
public int hashCode(){
 //your implementation 
}
@Override
 public boolean equals(){
  // your implementation 
 }
}
```

And then you can use :

```
Set<ArrayWrapper> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: It's almost always an error to override hashCode and not equals--even if the hashcode is well-written this isn't guaranteed to work in the face of collisions, and even then, you don't actually specify how one would go about writing an appropriate hashCode for this problem.

Comment: I think that this is a reasonable approach (compared to some of the alternatives suggested here), and I picked it up in my answer. The answer is a bit too short and sketchy for a +1, though (sorry...)

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want is a set of sets of integers, and if the relative order is important to you, you may use something like this:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        Set<Set<Integer>> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        int[] x = {1, 2, 3};
        int[] z = {2, 1, 3};
        int[] m = {2, 1, 3};

        result.add(Arrays.stream(x).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)));
        result.add(Arrays.stream(z).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)));
        result.add(Arrays.stream(m).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)));

        System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

You could also extract `Arrays.stream(x).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))` in a separate function.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
    public void testArraysSet() {
        Set<int[]> myArrays = new TreeSet<>((arr1, arr2) -> {
            Arrays.sort(arr1);
            Arrays.sort(arr2);
            return Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2) ? 0 : 1;
        });

        int [] a = {1,2,3};
        int [] b = {2,1,3};
        int [] c = {2,1,3};

        myArrays.add(a);
        myArrays.add(b);
        myArrays.add(c);

        assertEquals(1, myArrays.size());
    }
```

This should do, the sorting might slow things down a little though. You might wanna look into a faster array comparaison.